# Codeigniter showing 404 error for javascript file

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Codeigniter shows an 404 error page, for a javascript file. The file is in a `js` folder. The file in question is `jquery.cookie.js`.

If I change the filename, then I can access the file.

There are no route settings or .htaccess rules for the file, but for some reason codeigniter is showing its default 404 page when the javascript file is accessed.

Comment: are you able to access other files in the same folder?

Comment: @swapnesh Yes I am able to access all other files in the folder. Even if I change the filename, I am able to access the file,but not when the filename is jquery.cookie.js

Comment: @WebNovice.. can u plz tell me how ur navigating to these files?

Comment: @swapnesh I noticed the error when some jquery functions were not working on the site. So, I tried accessing the JS file directly with its URL, its showing me the CI 404 page. The `js` folder is located in the root folder. The folder does not contain any `.htaccess` or even an `index.html` file. When I go to `www.mysite.com/js`, it lists all the files including the problematic file, but when I click on it, it takes me to CI 404 page. It doesn't happen with the other files that are listed.

Comment: ..u can try by renaming your .htaccess file and let me know if it works or not

Comment: @swapnesh doesn't work. ok, I have renamed the file, and changed the references in all other files. Things seem to be working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12682/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-webnovice)

Comment: @WebNovice..plz check my chat link if something still left :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out what the problem was. Any file that has "cookie" in its filename was blocked by mod_security on our server.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before - the problem stems from CI's well intentioned security system that looks for certain malicious strings. I never tracked down exactly where it does it, but if a JS file name contains ".cookie" it'll be denied by CI's internal filter.

The quick fix is to just rename the file to not include the word cookie, or change the `.` in the filename to a `_`.

Comment: where does it say that codeigniter has a security system like that? If there is, CI should mention it. Wasted a lot of time looking for what caused it. I changed the filename to `jquery.cookie1.js` and it worked.